# Limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\},$ defined as follows: $$x_n=\dfrac{a+aa+aaa+aaaa\cdots+aaaaaaa..aaa }{10^n},$$ where $a\in\{1,2\ldots,9\}.$

$aaaaaaa..aaa = a , n$ time

Can anyone help ?

Comment: I edited your question. Now, if that's not what you meant then edit it, but try to be as specific as you can.

Comment: its not what u just wrote , its aa + aaa + aaaa .... + aaaaaaa.aaa..aaaa , n time

Comment: for example for a = 1 we have 1 + 11 + 111 + 1111 + 11111 .... + 1111111..1111

Comment: Then edit your question and clarify that point to avoid confutions.

Comment: Can u edit it please ? I think i won't express it well

Comment: @Faker123 1) please use mathjax, 2) please don't ask other users to write your questions properly, 3) please show what you have tried.

Comment: Am I supposed to read this as $x_n = \{ \frac{a + aa + aaa + ... + aa..aa}{10^n} \mid a \in \{1,2, ... ,9\} \} $

Comment: Ok. Let me help you a little. First, you need to know how you can simplify a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Second, note that $\dfrac{n}{10^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ (you can prove this using the binomial theorem).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you mean the following:
$$x_n = \frac{a}{10^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}10^j$$
Assuming this is the case, first note that the inner sum can be computed in closed form. For any constant $c \neq 1$, we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c^j = \frac{c^k - 1}{c - 1}$$
so for $c = 10$ this is
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}10^j = \frac{1}{9}(10^k - 1)$$
Substituting this back into the original expression gives us
$$x_n = \frac{a}{9\cdot 10^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(10^k - 1)$$
We can evaluate the sum as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(10^k - 1)
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n}1 \\
&= 10\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k - n \\
&= \frac{10}{9}(10^n - 1) - n \\
\end{aligned}$$
Substituting this into the previous expression, we end up with
$$\begin{aligned}
x_n &= \frac{a}{9\cdot 10^n}\left( \frac{10}{9}(10^n - 1) - n \right) \\
&= \frac{10a}{81}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{10^n}  \right) - \frac{na}{9 \cdot 10^n}\\
\end{aligned}$$
In the limit as $n \to \infty$, the second term converges to zero, and the first term converges to $10a/81$. Therefore we conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \frac{10a}{81}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a+aa+aaa+aaaa
\cdots+aaaaaaa..aaa }{10^n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{aaaaaaa..aaa}{10^n-10^{n-1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k}{10^n-10^{n-1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a\frac{10^n-1}{9}}{9\cdot 10^{n-1}}\\
&=&\frac{10a}{81}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @Bungo so which one is correct xd ?

Comment: Can u explain more from line 1 to line 2 please ?

Comment: Explain more please from line 1 to line 2

Comment: @xpaul Consider $a=1$ and $n=5$. Then $x_n = (1 + 11 + 111 + 1111 + 11111)/10^5 = 12345/100000 = 0.12345$. Your solution says that this should be closed to $1/81 = 0.012345...$, so you are off by a factor of $10$.

Comment: @Bungo, now I know where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Faker123, $aaa...a=a\cdot111...1=a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^k$.

Comment: @xpaul That's a nice theorem, I don't think I have encountered it before. (+1)

Comment: @Bungo, it is very useful. I learned this when I was an under from my professor.